# Looking for java html parser like simple html dom in PHP

Tags: java, php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am Looking for java html parser like (I know java well vs my bad php - in this way i want understand how html parser works) simple html dom in PHP.

thanks

Comment: I guess I didn't get the question correctly..  but did you google for "Java html parser" ?

Comment: Yes, I just want similar parser engine like in simple html dom, i dont have parpose to use it i just want to understand from the code how its works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It is the best HTML parser as far as I know.

Comment: @Yosef: my suggestion if you want to understand how the parser works is to download the source jar, and step through a parse in your IDE's debugger.

Specifically, see the parse() method in http://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.java

It is a recursive descent parser that looks at the next characters in the HTML queue, and depending on current context will create child elements, or text data, or pop up the element stack when a close tag is found.

The simplicity of the parse is somewhat complicated by handling dodgy input HTML.

(I'm the author of jsoup)

Answer (score 1):

Try [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), a SAX parser that takes in real-world messy HTML and triggers SAX XML events on your ContentHandler. I recommend using this with [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) to build a JDOM Document that you can walk manually, or via XPath.